# Xamarin Forms Debug Battery Drain

Tags: c#, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.forms

For the past 6 months i developed a XF app for a client.
Now we run into the problem that the app is heating up the phone really fast and it drains battery super fast.
Is there any good way to debug what in my app is causing this?

Some specialties about my app:
It accesses the camera most of the time the app is running.
It syncs small data with a webservice ever 15 seconds (2 Calls done with System.Net.Http.HttpClient)

I'm working with Visual studio

Comment: CPU/GPU and Screen are *typically* the largest wattage draws, next are GPS, cellular and wireless and other chipsets (i.e. camera and flash). Profiling your app's CPU usage would be a start, Google also has set of guides : https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/index.html

Comment: Camera is probably what is heating it up. Especially on phones that can do 4k recordings, many of them don't allow more than 10 minutes of continuous recording due to heat issues. Also as @SushiHangover mentions, profile your app. However, what you do from your description is very resource intensive things. Waking up the device every 15 seconds to grab an image and send data = huge battery drain.

Comment: @Aytee have you discovered anything interesting?